# Same html form performing different actions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i am in a scenario where i have these **data rows**.

```
<a id="login" href="#"><img src="images/edit_ico.png" alt="Edit" title="Edit"  border="0" id="<?php echo $key['sub_Id'];?>" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a id="login" href="#"><img src="images/del_ico.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" border="0" id="<?php echo $key['sub_Id'];?>" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a id="login" href="#"><img src="images/suspend_ico.png" alt="Suspend" title="Suspend" border="0" id="<?php echo $key['sub_Id'];?>" /></a>
            </td>
```

that is records of different subscribers and against them the edit, suspend and delete image.
on click i open the jquery dialog where the admin enter the user name and password for each action.
i've to get the subscriber id against each action on that form and perform that specific action.
**here is my form**

```
<div id="box" align="center">
</div>
<form name="loginform" id="confirm_action" method="post" action="process_form.php?action=<?php echo"1"; ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()">User Name:
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="User Name..."/>
    <br/>Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password..." />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
    <button type="button" id="cancel"> Cancel</button>
```

and the **jquery to load this form**

```
$('a#login').click(function(){
$("#box").fadeIn('slow');
$('form').fadeIn('slow');
})
```

when the form loaded how do i perform different opertion by geting the id in image id field.

Comment: get id in input filed but hide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not use same id for different links use a same CSS class name instead. You can use JQuery data  to get data inside image or link

refer to this
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Eg:

```
<a class="login" data-id="<?php echo $key['sub_Id'];?>" data-action="edit" href="#"><img src="images/edit_ico.png" alt="Edit" title="Edit"  border="0" /></a>

<a class="login" data-id="<?php echo $key['sub_Id'];?>" data-action="delete" href="#"><img src="images/delete_ico.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete"  border="0" /></a>
```

Comment: awesome mate thumbs upppp.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden input on your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sub_id" id="sub_id" value="" />
```

It won't be shown to the user, but sent to your server-side script on form submission. Update it's value with JavaScript & jQuery when showing the form:

```
$('a#login').click(function(){
    $("#box").fadeIn('slow');
    $('form').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#sub_id').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

You could add another hidden field for storing the action to perform.

Note, that I strongly recommend using another attribute than "id" on your image tag, because the id has to be **unique**. Rather, use the `data` attributes introduced in HTML 5 as suggested by Chatura Dilan in his answer. This would result in an image tag like:

```
<img src="images/edit_ico.png" alt="Edit" title="Edit" border="0" data-subscriber="<?php echo $key['sub_Id'];?>" />
```

You then can retrieve the id in JavaScript by `$(this).data('id')` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: if he really want to use Id then he do this <input type="hidden" name="sub_id" id="sub_id[]" value="" />

Comment: @callidior first thumbs up for ur excellent suggestion but after this how to get the value of that hidden field to perform action on form???

Comment: Where do you want to perform that action? It seems like your form is submitted to a script on your server. There, the values of the hidden fields will be available like those of any other fields. So, you can access the subscriber id as `$_POST['sub_id']`. Use another hidden field with another name and id for your action identifier.